# All subsets efficient implementation

Tags: python, algorithm

I need to get all subsets of [0..n-1] which doesn't contain any set from E.
Naive implementation:

```py
from itertools import combinations

n = 4
E = [(0, 1)]
[c for k in range(1, n + 1) 
   for c in combinations(range(n), k) 
   if not any(set(e).issubset(c) for e in E)]
```

In my case it won't be one-liner, because the set `E` will be dynamically populated over iterations, but the implementation will be similar. The problem is this works only for small `n`, while in real use-case `n ~ 100-1000`.

---

```py
n = 20
E = sum([list(combinations(range(n), k)) for k in range(2, 5)], [])
E = choices(E, k=int(len(E) * 0.95))
E = [set(e) for e in E]
print(len(E))

E = [e for e in E if not any(e.issubset(c) for c in E if c != e)]
print(len(E))

res = [c for k in range(1, n + 1) for c in combinations(range(n), k) if not any(e.issubset(c) for e in E)]
print(len(res))
```

Comment: Does `E` always contain 2-item entries or there could be entries of random size?

Comment: What will E contain for n = 100k - asked differently: how many sets will you expect the output to have? Because generating (and storing) a few 10+k sets all with different 10+k elements will simply take time. Why do you needs this at all?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest no, E might contain arbitrary set of size from 2 to n-1

Comment: Can you confirm that max `n` is 1000 in your case?

Comment: @luk2302 I need this to implement inclusion-exclusion principle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76851814/inclusion-exclusion-principle-implementation
In my case `n` will be ~100-1000.
I also expect that for large enough `k`, `E` will contain all subsets of length `k`

Comment: There are 2^n potential subsets, you need to ***massively*** reduce that number. No algorithm in the world can generate all those subsets in reasonable time.

Comment: @luk2302 indeed! That's why I've introduced set `E` to filter out unnecessary sets.

Comment: @vladkkkkk, and what is the real relation/ratio between `len(E)` and `n` in your real case?

Comment: Note that converting from `e` to `set(e)` is costly and you don't need to repeat that cost at every iteration. Before the first loop, convert every element of `E` into a set: `E_ = {set(e) for e in E}`

Comment: @Stef, *the set E will be dynamically populated over iterations*

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I don't have exact numbers right now, but it will be tunable parameter on how much percentage of subsets I add to `E` at each iteration of `k`. For, say, `k=6` I expect `E` will contain all subsets of `[0..n-1]`